Azure pipelines - dynamically get variable
I have defined a variable called tst-my--variable, and another one uat-my--variable in my azure pipeline like below.

When I'm running the azure-pipelines.yml, I'm checking the environment in which the pipeline is executing and defining a variable "environmentName".
After that I want to get one of those "tst-my--variable" "uat-my--variable" by concatenating the variable "environmentName" value with the text "-my--variable".
but nothing is working.
steps:
- script: | 
    echo $MY_ENV
  env:
    MY_ENV: $($(environmentName)-my--variable)

I already checked this article but didn't help.

You're trying to do things that are too dynamic IMO. Your problem can be solved with  ${{ if ... }} conditions, or for example trying to load a variables template based on $(environmentName)

Hi @GlennMateus, Have you got a chance to check the answers below to use different variable syntax based on how your variable environmentName is defined? Hope the information may help resolve your concerns. Thx.

This is not a direct answer to your question, but allow me to suggest a different approach to solve your problem.
1. Create variables template for each environment
As per Variables reuse, create a separate template to store each environment's variables:
TEST variables:
# /pipelines/variables/tst-variables.yaml

variables:
  - name: MY_ENV
    # use another variable's value or, as an alternative, an hard-coded value
    value: $(tst-my--variable)

  # Other TEST-related variables here

UAT variables:
# /pipelines/variables/uat-variables.yaml

variables:
  - name: MY_ENV
    # use another variable's value or, as an alternative, an hard-coded value
    value: $(uat-my--variable)

  # Other UAT-related variables here

2. Reference the variables template based on the environment
The below example pipeline uses a pipeline parameter for the environment, as opposed to a pipeline variable.
The parameter is then used to dynamically reference the right variables template:
parameters:
  - name: environmentName
    displayName: 'Environment Name'
    type: string
    default: 'tst'
    values:
      - 'tst'
      - 'uat'

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.environmentName }}-variables.yaml

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - script: | 
      echo "$(MY_ENV)"
    displayName: 'Print the value of pipeline variable'


Assuming the value for your variable $(environmentName) is defined during pipeline runtime rather than at compile time, which may prevent the pipeline from including the variable template in template expression syntax, it is suggested you directly use output variables during runtime. Here is a sample for your refernce.
variables:
  test-my--variable: test123
  uat-my--variable: uat456

steps:
- bash: |
    if [ "$(environmentName)" = "test" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_ENV;isoutput=true]$(test-my--variable)"
    elif [ "$(environmentName)" = "uat" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_ENV;isoutput=true]$(uat-my--variable)"
    fi
  name: OutputVar
- script: |
    echo "$(OutputVar.MY_ENV)"


See more samples to Set an output variable for use in future jobs and Set an output variable for use in future stages.


I want to get one of those "tst-my--variable" "uat-my--variable" by concatenating the variable "environmentName" value with the text "-my--variable".

Based on your requirement, you are using nested variable in YAML Pipeline.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the following methods:
1.If you are defining the environmentName variable in YAML file(the variable can be read in compile time), you can use the format: $(${{variables.environmentName}}-my--variable).
Here is an example:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  environmentName: tst

steps:
- script: | 
    echo $MY_ENV
  env:
    MY_ENV: $(${{variables.environmentName}}-my--variable)

Result:


If you are using windows agent, you need to use the following format:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  environmentName: tst

steps:
- powershell: | 
    echo $env:NAME
  env:
    MY_ENV: $(${{variables.environmentName}}-my--variable)

Refer to this doc: Environment variables
2.If you are defining the environmentName variable in variable group or running pipeline -> variable tab(the variable can be read in runtime), you the Variable Set task from extension: Variable Toolbox.
Here is an example:
steps:
- task: VariableSetTask@2
  inputs:
    variableName: MY_ENV
    Value: '$($(environmentName)-my--variable)'
 
- script:  echo $(MY_ENV)

